# How to create a short jQuery code according to the pattern?

Tags: jquery

I have a long list elements `<li>` in my html code:

```
<li class="pl1"><a href="#">some</a></li>
<li class="pl2"><a href="#">something</a></li>
<li class="pl3"><a href="#">something1</a></li>
```

And somewhere else in html code objects:

```
<span id="pl1">.</span>
<span id="pl2">.</span>
<span id="pl3">.</span>
```

And I wrote a script that adds class named `focus` in according pattern:

```
$("li.pl1").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#pl1").addClass("focus");
});
$("li.pl2").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#pl2").addClass("focus");
});
$("li.pl3").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#pl3").addClass("focus");
});
```

The only problem is that the code would have to be long. How to write a short jQuery code according to this pattern?

Comment: Are you just wanting a hover style? why not use the psuedo class :hover?

Comment: You cay `class="pl1"`, yet use the selector `#pl1` (which selects an element whose id is `pl1`).  Is this discrepancy intentional?  Or do you want the class "focus" to be added to the current list element?

Comment: I have to add class `focus` to different objects. Outside of `<li>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with BNL's approach...if at all possible modify your html so that you use the same class.  However if that isn't possible you could try using the [starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$('[class^="pl"]').mouseenter(function() {
   $('#' + $(this).attr("class")).addClass("focus");
});
```

This will give you what you want (I think) but there are better ways to do this.  For instance I'm not sure what will happen if you start adding classes to your LI's.

Using an attribute that starts with "data-" is a generally accepted way of passing information into your function.  If you have the ability to change your html you may want to consider:

```
<li class="pl" data-affectedId="pl1"><a href="#">some</a></li>
```

Then the jquery changes to:

```
$(".pl").mouseenter(function() {
   $("#"+$(this).attr("data-affectedId")).addClass("focus");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Apply a single class to all of the items and a data attr to store the corresponding id.

```
<li class="pl" data-itemid="pl1"><a href="#">some</a></li>
<li class="pl" data-itemid="pl2"><a href="#">some thing else</a></li>
```

And apply the event to that class and retrieve the ID from the data:

```
$(".pl").mouseenter(function() {
    $('#' + $(this).data("itemid")).addClass("focus");
});
```

You probably also want a mouseout function. You could use `hover` instead.

Comment: `pl1` and `#pl1` (class vs id) are different entities (from what the asker has revealed).  I'll ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of steps:

1. Add a common class for the list items, let's say "focusable-item"
2. Add a parent element to act as an event delegation target
3. Add a delegation handler to the parent element. For better re-usability, let's give it the class 'focusable'
4. Rejoice

And the markup:

```
<ul class="focusable>
  <li class="pl1 focusable-item"><a href="#">some</a></li>
  <li class="pl2 focusable-item"><a href="#">something</a></li>
</ul>

// jQuery code
$('.focusable').delegate('.focusable-item', {
  mouseenter: function () {
    $(this).addClass('focus');
  },
  mouseleave: function () {
    $(this).removeClass('focus');
  }
}
```